# Forest rings shape regularity

Tags: geophysics, forest

In the [answer to "Why is ground water rising on these forest rings?"](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/8245/11353) it is written:

> these rings are too numerous and too regular in shape to be related to either kimberlites or (even more bizarrely) Oklo-type natural nuclear reactors

How is the regularity of forest rings assessed? How many near-rings and other shapes have been found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my correspondence with Dr. Hamilton, who is one of the leading researchers on forest rings (emphasis mine):

> They can be irregular (see figure below) but it is not very common. You
> are right, the circularity is why we notice them and there are
> probably lots that we don’t notice because they are not round.
> However, the mechanism of formation that we have postulated ought to
> produce circular shapes. All point-source force fields in an isotropic
> medium will produce a circle if the area of influence is large enough.
> We argue that the source of energy is the electrochemical potential
> (redox) difference between the inside and outside of the ring; and the
> force is an electrical field. The groundwater and glacial overburden
> have fairly isotropic electrical conductivity (the inverse of
> resistance) and therefore **circularity is a requirement if the current
> density is sufficient**.
>
> [image: various forest rings of various sizes and shapes]
> This photo was taken near from northeastern Ontario north of Kapuskasing. The circular ring is  ~150m across.